# Regex Convert two or more escapes to single escape and only a single escape to two escapes

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find a regex solution to this problem. Which is

1. Check if a string has a single backslash "\" then convert it to
   double backslash "\"
2. Check if a string has two or more
   consecutive backslashes convert to double backslash.

Can anyone please help me come up with a pattern.
I know how to check if a string has more than two backslashes

```
/\\\\\\+/g
```

However I am not sure how to check for the second case. Also is there a way to combine both

example

`ab\\\cd\` should be `ab\\cd\\`

`a\cd\\\\\\\e\` should be `a\\cd\\e\\`

inshort any no of consecutive slashes either 1 or n should be replaced by two.

Update :
Sorry for the bad examples. I did not use code formatting so my examples were not being displayed correctly

Comment: Can you give a few examples, because the details are still not clear to me.

Comment: sure let me update it

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"\\+", "\\\\");?`

Comment: I read it as "replace any 1 or more backslashes with 2 backslashes", [``Regex.Replace(text, @"\\+", @"\\")``](https://ideone.com/pypz0M)

Comment: and, for what  platform do you need the regex? There are some subtle platform differences in syntax

Comment: This question is confusing - do you want to replace 1 backslash with 2, or 2 or more with 1?

Comment: @martin any no of backslashes should be replaced by two. so no mater how many backslashes there are they should be replaced with 2. for example a single backslash will be replaced by two . If there were 4 consecutive backslashes they will be replaced by only two.

Comment: @MistyD Why do your examples show a single backslash in the output then?

Comment: @Martin I think @MistyD is a little confused about escaping. `"\\"` in code will print as `"\"`, so I think OP is talking about "2 backslashes in the code representation, so that only 1 will be printed"

Comment: @Martin sorry let me fix those

Comment: @MindSwipe That makes sense now I think about what you've said.  Is the intended _output_ a single backslash (but appears as a double backslash in _unescaped_ C# string)?

Comment: @Martin yup, that's what I was trying to get across, I think the question confused me to the point where English became hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is asking how to replace any instances of two or more backslashes with a single backslash, so as per OP's question:

```
ab\\cd\ becomes ab\cd\
a\cd\\\\e\ becomes a\cd\e\
```

Try this code, which replaces any matches that have two or more backslashes with a single one:

```
private string DoReplace(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\\+", @"\");
}
```

Testing:

```
Console.WriteLine(DoReplace(@"ab\\cd\"));
Console.WriteLine(DoReplace(@"a\cd\\\\e\"));
```

Output:

```
ab\cd\
a\cd\e\
```

**Edit following double-backslash discussion in comments**

Following OP comment about potentially wanting to *output* a double-backslash, the following modified Regex will achieve this (note the double `\\` now as the replacemenet text):

```
private string DoReplace(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\\+", @"\\");
}
```

Output:

```
ab\\cd\\
a\\cd\\e\\
```

Comment: sorry my examples were messed up since i did not use code formatting. Actually i want only double backslashes whereever there is a backslash or group of backslashes

Comment: @MistyD Just to clarify beyond doubt - you want a double backslash _in the output_?

Comment: YES. No matter how many consecutive backslashes there are  (1 or n) they should be replaced with 2.

Comment: @MistyD See my updated answer in that case, which shows how to achieve this with a simple tweak the the replacement text

Comment: Yep I think this will work. Let me try it

Comment: that did the trick

Comment: @MistyD Great stuff, glad to have helped